# google play services sdk missing

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to make a simple app which will have a view containing the google maps sdk.  I am following along with this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code however none of the files/folders which they say are there... are actually there.  I need the google play services sdk and I have no idea where to get it.  I have tried many different things to get it to show up in the Android SDK manager, but it will not... is there a direct link online I could get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely because incomplete files in your sdk.firewall of ur office or somewhere blocks it and hence error message comes saying peer not authenticated I was facing the same problem but after downloading all the files by getting firewall access My emulator is working properly and much faster than before. And the api's also got included in SDK manager so stop the firewall by blocking and download the important files this will surely do the work....

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly found it was due to a company firewall issue, which identifies the root issue as the SDK Manager is unable to connect and download the repository list.

A minor addendum, for others like me who are looking for this answer from outside the US, countries such as China have blocked some connections to the Google servers, so a personal VPN is the work-around.

And if you're using an application/browser level VPN then the SDK Manager will not make use of this connection, so you will have to find the loopback port in order to set the proxy in the SDK Manager ->Tools->Options menu.  FYI, Astrill VPN users should set it to 127.0.0.1:3213

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem .In SDK manager go to tool->options and give your HTTP Proxy server and Http Proxy port

Answer (score -1):

You need to launch `SDK Manager` and install `Google Play Services` package (platform independent, from `Extras` node). Then you will have it on your machine in `<SDK>\extras\google\google_play_services` folder.

Comment: as I mentioned... google play services SDK is not located inside of the SDK manager for me

Comment: the folder <SDK>\extras exists, but the folder <SDK>\extras\google does not exist

Comment: maybe you got some sort of ancient SDK manager? tried refetching new one? or doing Packages -> Reload

Comment: I was thinking that so I tried reloading the ADT bundled with eclipse but to no avail.  The issue turned out to be that the company I work for--their firewall was blocking the SDK manager from downloading anything from google as it worked fine as soon as I went home